# What screws should I use to screw Wedi boards into wood studs using Wedi washers?

Tags: tile, waterproofing, backer-board

I'm building a waterproof bath area with shower head.

I have 12.5mm Wedi tile backer board and Wedi washers, for fixing the board onto wood studs.

I was hoping to buy "Wedi screws" but the Wedi system seems to assume that the buyer will supply their own.

What sort of screws should I buy, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at their web site, it appears that "Wedi board" is, effectively, a foam version of drywall appropriate for both wet & dry locations. (I looked it up because I had no clue what it was. I included the info here because I figure others in the US may not know either.)

Their web site shows the washers installed with a Phillips head screw through the center hole which appears to be recessed slightly from the surface.

- A pan-head screw would work nicely because it's got a flat bottom to hold nicely in the flat of the washer's recess, however the domed top may stick up above the recess and create a bump in the finished surface. At a minimum, your tile mastic (making assumptions...) would have to be thick enough to cover the screw head. If you can find a pan-head with a shallow dome available with a waterproofing treatment, that may be the way to go.
- A typical wood screw has a sloped shoulder that will crush into the washer's recess a little bit, but has a flat top that you should be able to get flush with the surface of the washer.

I would think that pretty much any wood screw would work in that situation.

- You could use a drywall screw, as those hold drywall up very well when screwed into studs. However, they're not really designed for wet locations and you may end up with corrosion and screws failing due to humidity and leaks.
- You could use a galvanized decking screw, since they're designed for holding in wood and are good for wet locations.
- You could use a screw designed for cement board, as these are similar to drywall screws, but are protected for use in wet locations.
- You could contact the manufacturer to ask what they recommend, then post that here as an answer to help others out.

Comment: The Wedi documentation recommends "...using commercially available wood or drywall screws and wedi Tools washers..." Screws that are designed for outdoor/high-moisture applications would be, I believe, preferable. I'd look at using the screws manufactured for other backer-board (e.g. cement board) applications as maybe being useful.

Comment: Thanks, @GregNickoloff, I was looking for that info and didn't find it. TBH, I didn't look _that_ hard...

Answer (score 1):

Wedi's website indicates the wedi boards (essentially large sheets of rigid foam with concrete surface) should be attached to substrate with adhesive (wedi 320) or directly to studs with another adhesive (wedi 610) and the washers are used with "metal dowels" only for leveling uneven surfaces (the given diagrams show partially-crumbled brick as an example of "uneven").

[Wedi installation guide (pdf download)](https://www.wedi.de/index.php?eID=ajaxDownloadMedium&attribute_value_id=8222&L=1)

[Wedi systems guide (pdf download)](https://www.wedi.de/index.php?eID=ajaxDownloadMedium&attribute_id=7715&L=1)

Comment: Good find. I was looking for an install guide and didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The Wedi documentation recommends "...using commercially available wood or
drywall screws and wedi Tools washers..."
Screws that are designed for outdoor/high-moisture applications would be, I believe, preferable. I'd look at using the screws manufactured for other backer-board (e.g. cement board) applications as maybe being useful.

[What Screws to Use With Cement Board](https://www.hunker.com/13401556/what-screws-to-use-with-cement-boards)